# Using a subquery for IN clause Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, in-clause

I am having some trouble using a subquery for the IN clause of a query.
Hard-coding the IN .. values allows the query to execute quickly, but using a subquery slows everything down. Is there a way to speed this query up?

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table1
WHERE ...
and col1 in (SELECT col1 FROM table2)
...
```

*The values for the IN clause will be a list of strings

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table1
WHERE ...
and col1 in ('str1', 'str2', 'str3', ...)
...
```

The above works fine.

EDIT:
I think I was oversimplifying the problem. The query I am trying to execute looks like this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, ...
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE t1.col1 IN (SELECT col FROM table3)
and t1.col2 < 50
and t2.col3 = t1.col3
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *JOIN* instead,

and keep an index defined on *table1.col1* or *table2.col3* or  *table1.col3* or *table3.col* :

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, ...
  FROM table1 t1
 INNER JOIN table2 t2 on ( t2.col3 = t1.col3 )
 INNER JOIN table3 t3 on ( t1.col1 = t3.col )
 WHERE t1.col2 < 50;
```

Answer (score 2):

You cant write `select * from`   . If you give select * from, it doesnot understand which column to compare with from table2. Use the column name you need.

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE ...
and col1 in (SELECT col1 FROM table2)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, standard `JOIN` syntax.  You should write the query as:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, ...
FROM table1 t1 JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t2.col3 = t1.col3
WHERE t1.col1 IN (SELECT col FROM table3) AND
      t1.col2 < 50;
```

I would write this using `EXISTS`, rather than `IN`:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, ...
FROM table1 t1 JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t2.col3 = t1.col3
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table3 t3 WHERE t1.col1 = t3.col) AND
      t1.col2 < 50;
```

The filtering is all on `table1`; however, the columns are being compared with inequalities.  I would try the following indexes:  `table2(col3)`, `table1(col2, col1)`, and `table3(col)`.

Comment: Is it possible that you've got a copy/paste error? The duplicate `SELECT 1 FROM` looks suspicious.

Comment: You're welcome. I've removed the duplicate `FROM`, as well.